# How to remove the Data item from the Datasource selection

Tags: sxa

When i add a component to the page and do associate content to the rendering, along with datasource location that i set in Datasource location field of the rendering, i get Data folder also. I need to remove the Data item that comes up in Datasource selection. Attaching the screenshot for the same 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of SXA functionality.

**Data** item represents page relative data source folder

By default you can store data source in:

- global folder `/sitecore/content/T/S/Data/Texts/Text1`
- page relative, under page `/sitecore/content/T/S/Home/tests/Data/Text2`)

if you will remove it you will hide/remove part of the functionality.

If you really want to remove it or show only in a certain scenario, patch this processor or add logic afterward.

```
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.LocalDatasources.Pipelines.GetRenderingDatasource.AddPageDataFolder, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.LocalDatasources" />
```

in **getRenderingDatasource** pipeline.

**Note**

Data folder that you highlighted is virtual until you actually create something underneath, which means it doesn't exist until you create first page relative data source.